# How to reduce the usage of IF - ELSE by reflection ? Can I get the code example

Tags: java, class, servlets, dynamic, reflection

I was trying to use reflection for the code of PizzaFactory Class so that I can remove the if else condition and make my code more dynamic. But I am not able to figure out how.

```
   Pizza.java
    package PizzaTrail;
   import java.util.List;

    //this is the main abstract factory which will be extended by the concrete factory 
    public abstract class Pizza {  public abstract List fetchIngredients(String Type); }


    PizzaFactory.java 
   package PizzaTrail;
   import java.util.List;

   //this is the concrete factory 
   public class PizzaFactory extends Pizza
   { 
        public static Pizza getConcretePizza(String PType)
        { 
          Pizza p=null;
          if (PType.equals("Cheese")) 
          {
                     p=new CheesePizza();
          } else if (PType.equals("Pepperoni")) 
          {
              p=new PepperoniPizza();
          }
           else if (PType.equals("Clam")) 
          {
               p = new CalmPizza();

           }
           else if (PType.equals("Veggie")) 
           {
               p= new VeggiePizza();

            }
            return(p); 
       }   
   }


     ChessePizza.java
     package PizzaTrail;

      import java.util.ArrayList;
      import java.util.List;

     public class CheesePizza extends Pizza {
      List ing = new ArrayList();
       @Override
       public List fetchIngredients(String Type)
       {
       ing.add("Ingredient : Shredded Mozzarella Cheese");
      ing.add("Ingredient : Peppers");
      ing.add("Ingredient : Feta cheese");
     ing.add("Ingredient : Pesto");
      return (ing);   
      }

    }

  }
```

Can anyone help me get the reflection used in the pizzaFactory class so that i can call the class CheesePizza, etc  dynamically?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: take a look at enum types, and the switch statement

Comment: I want to replace the if else by Reflection method. Its like can I call the class dynamically. can i write only few lines of code and it will check and get the particular class called. without if else... but using reflection. is it possible?

Comment: Why does PizzaFactory extend Pizza???? Just for fun?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question in terms of reducing 'if-else' usage, you *could* dynamically determine the class to use e.g. instead of

```
if (PType.equals("Cheese")) {
    p=new CheesePizza();
```

you could use

```
Class.forName(PType + "Pizza").newInstance(); // might need a package
```

(the above assumes a no-args constructor)

and that would remove any switching-type behaviour.

However *I wouldn't recommend this*. The above is difficult to debug and non-obvious. Your IDE will likely mark such classes as not being used and a possible candidate for removal during a future refactor. I would favour clarity in the vast majority of cases.

In short, I would much rather specify the specifications of available pizzas via an if/else sequence, a String-based switch, a map of strings to method objects etc. rather than any convoluted, non-obvious, perhaps fragile mechanism.

Comment: thank you ! Your answer was simple and I applied the same logic. It working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

You could provide the class of the concreate pizza to the factory method -

```
public static <T extends Pizza> T getConcretePizza(Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        return clazz.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the solution it helped me get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Bearing in mind that using reflection to solve a problem usually leaves you with two problems - how about using an `enum`?

```
enum Pizzas {

    Cheese {

                @Override
                Pizza make() {
                    return new CheesePizza();
                }

            },
    Pepperoni {

                @Override
                Pizza make() {
                    return new PepperoniPizza();
                }

            },
    Clam {

                @Override
                Pizza make() {
                    return new ClamPizza();
                }

            },
    Veggie {

                @Override
                Pizza make() {
                    return new VeggiePizza();
                }

            };

    abstract Pizza make();

    public static Pizza make(String type) {
        return Pizzas.valueOf(type).make();
    }
}

public void test() {
    Pizza pizza = Pizzas.make("Cheese");
}
```

Comment: This seems far less horrifying. Depending on how the rest of the program works it might be possible to remove the the string dependancy entirely and use enums throughout

Comment: @RichardTingle - Just using the enums is a much better option.

Comment: @RichardTingle Tingle thank you for your valuable suggestions. But without using ENUM and only using Reflection served the purpose. It also made the code not Horrifying.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon  thank you for your valuable answer. But without using ENUM and only using Reflection served the purpose. It also made the code not Horrifying. will surely use ENUM where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have your interface pizza
`public interface Pizza { \*some methods *\}`

and implementations such as `public class CheesePizza implements Pizza {}`

you could create enum `PizzaType`

```
enum PizzaType {
    Cheese(CheesePizza.class);
    Class<?> type;
    PizzaType(Class<?> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    Pizza create() {
    try {
        return (Pizza) type.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
            }
    }
    }
```

now to create new fresh pizza all what you need to do is

`Pizza pizza = PizzaType.Cheese.create();`

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain such a map:

```
private static final Map<String, Class<? extends Pizza>> PIZZAS;

static {
    Map<String, Class<? extends Pizza>> pizzas = new HashMap<String, Class<? extends Pizza>>();
    pizzas.put("Cheese", CheesePizza.class);
    pizzas.put("Pepperoni", PepperoniPizza.class);
    PIZZAS = Collections.unmodifiableMap(pizzas);
}
```

Then, for example:

```
public static Pizza getConcretePizza(String type) {
    Class<? extends Pizza> clazz = PIZZAS.get(type);
    if (clazz == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No pizza of type " + type);
    }
    try {
        return clazz.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to instantiate pizza of type " + clazz.getSimpleName(), e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to avoid the use of conditions with reflection, otherwise your code will fail at some point. However, given your request, you can do this:

```
public static Object getConcretePizza(String type) throws Exception{
    String pizza = String.format("pizza_trail.%sPizza", type);
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(pizza);
    Object pizzaClass = clazz.newInstance();

    return pizzaClass;
}
```

Then, during implementation, you can determine the type of pizza you want using the if condition checks:

```
Object pizzaObject = PizzaFactory.getConcretePizza("Cheese");
if(pizzaObject instanceof CheesePizza){
    CheesePizza pizza = (CheezePizza) pizzaObject;
    // call CheesePizza related methods here.

}
```

P.S. I have noticed that you're using Camelcase in your package name. make it a habit of using lowercase letters for packages, and where multiple words are involved, use an underscore. This is just the Java convention, though not a requirement.

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
      //public static Pizza getConcretePizza(String PType){


      public static Pizza getConcretePizza(Class cType){


     /**
      *

      if (PType.equals("Cheese")) 
      {
                 p=new CheesePizza();
      }//..............  
       */


    Constructor  ctor = cType.getConstructor();
    Object object = ctor.newInstance();
    p = object; 


     //....
      }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post an explanation why your answer works, then the questioner/others will have a better idea of why it works.